# Matching password pattern in files using regex in egrep

Tags: grep

I am trying to find files along with the matching password pattern under a given directory on linux using egrep. The pattern found in the files is typically as follows

1. `password=value`
2. `pwd=value`
3. `pass=value`

- A  file that is matched can contain atleast one of the above patterns for the password
  anywhere in the file.
- There can be **one of more spaces** or **none**    on either side of
  the **=** sign.
- The value can either be enclosed in **single** or **double** or **have no
  quotes** surrounding it.
- The value **cannot** begin with a **curly brace {** or a **single**  **ampersand** **&**
  or ****double** ampersand &&**

Examples of the patterns that **should be** matched in the files

`password = "test123ABc#&$"`

`pwd=test123ABc#&$`

`pwd =    'test123ABc#&$'`

`pass  =    'test123456&'`

Examples of patterns that **should not** be matched in the files

`password=&testpw`

`pwd = "{test123@#"`

`password  =   "&&test123"`

`pass={test123@`

I currently have this egrep command where i am trying to find the appropriate regex expression to carry out the above task. But the world of regex has just left me confused even though there are resources online.  Appreciate any help on this.

`egrep -HRi "<regex expression>"  <path to directory>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If PCRE is allowed, which can be enabled using the -P flag in grep.

```
(password|pwd|pass) *= *+((?=".*")"[^&{][^\s]*"|(?='.*')'[^&{][^\s]*'|(?=[^"'{&].*)[^\s]*)$
```

Explanation:

- `(password|pwd|pass) *= *+((?=".*")"[^&{][^\s]*"|(?='.*')'[^&{][^\s]*'|(?=[^"'{&].*)[^\s]*)$`

  - `(password|pwd|pass)` matches the literal password phrases specified.
  - `*= *+` matches any number of spaces, followed by `=` followed by any number of spaces possessively
  - `((?=".*")"[^&{][^\s]*"|(?='.*')'[^&{][^\s]*'|(?=[^"'{&].*)[^\s]*)$`

    - `(?=".*")"[^&{][^\s]*"`

      - `(?=".*")` positive lookahead that looks for any character around `"`
      - `"[^&{][^\s]*"` matches string not led by `&` or `{`
    - `(?='.*')'[^&{][^\s]*'`

      - `(?='.*')` positive lookahead that looks for any character around `'`
      - `'[^&{][^\s]*'` matches string not led by `&` or `{`
    - `(?=[^"'{&].*)[^\s]*`

      - `(?=[^"'{&].*)` positive lookahead that looks if string does not start with `"` `'` `{` `&`.
      - `[^\s]*` matches rest of string
    - `$` matches end of line

Try it here on
https://regex101.com/r/oIEZSS/1

Answer (score 1):

@Abhishek G 's excellent expression did the trick for me. I used the grep command to find the patterns as follows. I did have to have escape few of the double quotes within the expression with backslashes and drop the $ symbol at the end.

```
grep -RiP "(password|pwd|pass) *= *+((?=".*")\"[^&{][^\s]*\"|(?='.*')'[^&{][^\s]*'|(?=[^\"'{&].*)[^\s]*)"  *.txt
```